# Pass data between view controllers

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I’m still fairly new to Objective C and xCode so please forgive me.

I have two view controllers setup in my storyboard and im using the following code to move to another:

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stageOne"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now this works great though in the class controlling the second view controller I have a property setup that Im attempting to send data to. I was attempting the following:

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stageOne"];
viewController.forename = @"Hello World";
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Though this does not work and all I get is an error "Propert 'forename' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'".

Any help is appreciated and if you are able to leave me with some example code that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is your accessing the uicontrols which are not yet created in the memory. You have to change the order of the execution of your statements like this...

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
holidayQuestion * viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stageOne"];

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
viewController.forename = @"Hello World";
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same error: "Propert 'forename' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'"

Comment: can u make sure that the property "forename" is declared properly or not in that view controller?

Comment: @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * forename;

Comment: in .h file only u have declare, for accessing out side of the class and modify.

Comment: in the header file of the objective Im sending from I have:
#import "holidayQuestion.h"

Comment: UIViewController * viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stageOne"];

in your scenario, the viewController is a instance of type "holidayQuestion"?  if yes, modify the the above line like this...



holidayQuestion * viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"stageOne"];

Comment: The code to switch between the view controllers works perfectly?

Comment: what is the name of the second view controller you want to display?

Comment: The name of the object is "holidayQuestion" though in the storyboard the viewcontroler identifier is "stageOne"

Comment: Perfect thank you ever so much for your help, though the two bottom lines now appear to be the wrong way around.

Comment: for your case, even if you change the order of bottom two lines also same result you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for pass data between 2 controllers, you can use 2 design patterns: [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW20) or [Observer.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW20)

In your case, you use delegate. Do you have public property with name `forename` in your header file?

Comment: The property is defined as: @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * forename;